# Working day counter for VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite new to VBA and I need to add something to code I've been given that will count the number of working days between a start date and today's date and output this data in a column at the end of my spreadsheet. My attempts so far have all failed, grateful for any help people can give!

Comment: Please show us what you already have and what you already tried.

Comment: Public Function WorkDayDiff(ByRef StartDate As Range) As Integer
        Set xlCell = Range("N2")
        For Counter = 1 To DateDiff("1", StartDate.Value, Now())
         If Weekday(CDate(StartDate.Value + Counter)) > 1 And Weekday(CDate(StartDate.Value + Counter)) < 7 Then WorkDayDiff = WorkDayDiff + 1
     Next Counter
    End Function

Comment: The issue I'm having is with the output into a column in my spreadsheet.

Comment: Next time please edit your question and try not to post code into a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly simple, see formula below:
`=NETWORKDAYS(C13,C14,calenderyear16)`

Put your start date in cell C13 (or wherever you need it), and end date in C14 (or wherever you need it).

`calenderyear16` is just a range of cells that i have named. You must also create the same named range. This named range contains all of the bank holidays in the year.

You can obtain the list of bank holidays for each year from Gov.uk website

In VBA:

`Range("C15").Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(C13,C14,calenderyear16)"`

you can change `range("C15")` to be `cells(row number, column number)` and you can use a dynamic range as well if you wish. hope this works! :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but my whole worksheet is generated by a macro which erases any data in it when you run the macro; this is why I need a solution I can fit into my code. Is there a way to paste this formula into my code?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go!

Comment: Hi, did this work for you? need any further development? :) Please mark as an answer if it was useful for you

Comment: Yes! Never knew you could put excel formulas in VBA like that. Thanks!

Comment: yep! you can also make it dynamic if range is unknown :)